# HTML5 - Canvas losing focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, focus

I'm making a game with Impact JS, which uses canvas to render. In the game I have button that shows a hidden div containing flow player, and plays a video. In that hidden div is also a button that closes the div and stops the video... all good so far. The problem is that once the video is closed, I have to click the canvas to get the focus back. So, a button that was under the video now has to be clicked twice to make it work... no good.
I've determined it's not specific to flowplayer. I can show a hidden div with just black in it and hide it in 5 seconds and the canvas still loses focus.
Anyone seen this? It's a showstopper at the moment.. really need to get it working.

Comment: OK, I went and added a click handler to the canvas tag and I find that canvas is actually not losing focus - as I get a 'canvas down' trace when I click the canvas, even though the button didn't reply.

I am using the Impact JS game engine for this, and it seems that's what is actually losing focus - though it is still running fine as my rollovers continue to work. 

If anyone cares to take a quick look, I have it on a staging site for a bit.
http://design.gmrstage.com/dave/chiltest/default.html#

Really appreciate any help here.

Comment: PS - if you decide to look - click arrow on main page to get to main menu. Click any button - video will open - click Menu to close video. Buttons will now take two clicks to work.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already applied a tabindex to your canvas.

Good, that's required to set focus to the canvas.

Now to give the canvas focus after the video ends, do this:

```
// get a reference to the canvas element

var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');

// set focus to the canvas when the video ends

canvas.focus().
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Well... it may, but as I explained later canvas seems to be keeping focus fine. I added a click handler in the canvas tag, and that function gets called - even though the button in game doesn't respond - until clicked again.

Comment: PS - if you look again you will see 'canvas down' traced to the console after the video closes, even though the button doesn't respond until you click a second time.